# Converting Unix Time with Offset to .NET DateTime

Tags: .net, datetime, unix-timestamp

I can't get my head around on how to convert something like

```
1332953228 -14400
```

to first-class `System.DateTime` object. This value actually comes from Mercurial an when displayed on the UI is seen as

```
Wed Mar 28 20:47:08 2012 +0400
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly how you should handle the timezone offset, but Unix Time is number of seconds since 1/1/1970.  This seems close, though like I said I'm not sure about the offset:

```
var theDate = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddSeconds(1332953228), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(-14400));
```